# UnboundID LDAP and Squid Proxy

Tags: java, squid, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I chose the UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java. I deployed, somewhere in cloud, a Bastion server and a Microsoft Active Directory in the same network. If I run the LDAP client code on the Bastion server, it works. Now I want to run the code locally. For this, I installed the Squid on the Bastion and I configured it to allow everything. I start the Java application with -Dhttp.proxyHost, -Dhttp.proxyPort, -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort.

I use the following method:

```
LDAPConnection(String host, int port, String bindDN, String password).
```

Using this approach doesn't work for me. I don't see the requests that are forwarded to the Squid proxy. I want to achieve this for developing purposes. I am new to this library.

Question: Does anybody achieved this before? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work. I am not aware of any open source LDAP client in Java or C which will utilize `CONNECT` to tunnel through an HTTP proxy. Especially as soon as you will use certs or Kerberos your jump server will not work.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would not be there a solution.